# No condition in a for loop?

Tags: c++

(Sorry in advance, this question is probably very simple. I write code as a hobby and am just trying to wrap my mind around some things right now.)

I recently encountered a loop statement like (`n` is a previously set positive integer):

```
int cnt;
for(cnt=0; n; cnt++){
    n &= n - 1;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the middle entry in a loop should be a condition, but `n;` does not seem to be a condition at all. Unless if it is understood as a bool (`true` if `n!=0` and `false` if `n==0`). If this is the correct way to think about it, would the following code be perfectly equivalent to the above?

```
int cnt=0;
while(n>0){
    n &= n - 1;
    cnt++;
}
```

If yes, why would one choose the former style of writing this instead of the while loop? It seems to me that a while loop would be the most clear and intuitive choice here, so I wonder if there is any advantage in the for loop that I missed? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: "clear and intuitive" is subjective, maybe the author of the code considers the `for` loop to be clearer? The only advantage I can think of is that the `for` loop is 1 line of code less.

Comment: @UnholySheep So you do imply that both code snippets are perfectly equivalent? Thank you for the information!

Comment: The `while` loop is *not* equivalent, the condition should be `n != 0` (or simply `n`) for it to be equivalent. Besides that it's almost how `for` loops are implemented.

Comment: Hmm, but `n` is defined to be `n>0`... How exactly are they different?

Comment: `n` is a **signed** integer, meaning it can have negative values as well. The `for` loop only ends when `n == 0`

Comment: The condition in the `for` loop is `n`, which is equivalent to `n != 0`. I'm just going about that. Remember that negative numbers are also non-zero and therefore true.

Comment: a loop that has an 'iteration part' (cnt++ in this case), should use for loop, a while loop would skip the iteration part upon `continue`

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you for your help! I think now I understand.

Comment: Probably I would have written it like `int cnt=0; for(; n; n&=n-1) ++cnt;`, to make the condition variable match the variable in the "increment", and make explicit that the actual objective of this loop is to calculate `cnt` (normally the variable that is incremented is a throwaway).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: No way that code passes review in my team!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why not? To me is way more sensible than what OP found. OTOH, I understand that my other alternative (`for(cnt=0; n; ++cnt, n&=n-1);`) could summon some perplexed looks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, the middle entry in a loop should be a condition, but n; does not seem to be a condition at all.

It is.

> Unless if it is understood as a bool (true if n!=0 and false if n==0).

Yes.

> If this is the correct way to think about it, would the following code be perfectly equivalent to the above?

Nearly; it's `n != 0`, not `n > 0`.

> If yes, why would one choose the former style of writing this instead of the while loop?

People do silly things all the time, for all sorts of reasons!

> It seems to me that a while loop would be the most clear and intuitive choice here

I agree.

> I wonder if there is any advantage in the for loop that I missed?

Nope.

Well, not for this one. If the loop body were different, say with more complex logic and a `continue` statement or two, the behaviour of the program might be different (if you forgot to increment `cnt` on your new code path). But that's not the case here.